# Android inflate layout crashes after adding fragment container view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

currently I have a custom drawer activity that extends AppCompatActivity, which looks like the following:

```
public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        ...
    }


    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_frame);
        LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout);
        super.setContentView(drawerLayout);
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see here, I overwrite the setContentView method, so the layout id of the activity that extend this drawer activity will be passed into this method and inflated in the drawer activity's subview. In a simple word, I want all activities that extend this drawer activity will have a navigation drawer. It works well for general acitivity.

But now, I have an activity that contains a fragment container view and extend the drawer activity. When I launch this activity, the application crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aaa, PID: 10730
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aaa/com.example.aaa.gym.GymActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.aaa:layout/activity_gym: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.aaa:layout/activity_gym: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.aaa:layout/activity_gym: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.aaa:layout/activity_gym: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.aaa:layout/activity_gym: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
        at com.example.aaa.DrawerActivity.setContentView(DrawerActivity.java:57)
        at com.example.aaa.gym.GymActivity.onCreate(GymActivity.java:62)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: FragmentContainerView must be within a FragmentActivity to use android:name="com.example.aaa.gym.PlaceFragment"
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:142)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:120)
            ... 28 more
```

As you can see here, the root cause is `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: FragmentContainerView must be within a FragmentActivity to use android:name="com.example.aaa.gym.PlaceFragment"`. However, the activity should be able to inflate fragments as it extends DrawerActivity and DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity, which extends Fragment Activity. I'm very confused about this.

Here is the activity code:

```
public class GymActivity extends DrawerActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private ActivityGymBinding binding;
    
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        markers = new ArrayList<>();

        binding = ActivityGymBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        // here crashes, the actual crash line is the second line of the drawer activity's setContentView
        setContentView(binding.getRoot().getSourceLayoutResId()); 

        ...

    }
    
    ...
}
```

And this is the activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".gym.GymActivity">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_gym"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/place_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.aaa.gym.PlaceFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/place_fragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the fragment, nearly nothing changed

```
public class PlaceFragment extends Fragment {

    private PlaceViewModel mViewModel;
    private PlaceFragmentBinding binding;

    public static PlaceFragment newInstance() {
        return new PlaceFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(PlaceViewModel.class);

        mViewModel.getName().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), s -> binding.name.setText(s));
        mViewModel.getLocation().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), s -> binding.location.setText(s));

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment.xml, just a simple framelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".gym.PlaceFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:text="Hello" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Can anyone see why my application crashes? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: can u answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77425186/22860597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout);
```

You are using the application context - that is specifically **not** your Activity and hence, does not use the Activity's theme, nor does your Application class extend `FragmentActivity`. You'll want to use `LayoutInflater.from(this)` to actually use your Activity as the layout inflater.

However, while that will fix your crash, your `GymActivity` still won't work because of these lines:

```
binding = ActivityGymBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

// here crashes, the actual crash line is the second line of the drawer activity's setContentView
setContentView(binding.getRoot().getSourceLayoutResId());
```

Here, you create a `binding` object, but never actually add it your Activity. Instead, you call through to your `setContentView` override that inflates a brand new instance of that View. This means that any changes to your `binding` won't ever be reflected in your UI.

Instead, you'd want to provide an override of your `setContentView` that takes a `View` and calls `addView` on your FrameLayout to add the already inflated View to your layout.

```
@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_frame);
    frameLayout.addView(view)
    // Note you should never be calling super.setContentView here.
    // You've already called it in your own onCreate()
}
```

Which lets you use it like:

```
binding = ActivityGymBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

Comment: Gosh! You are genius XD